# Cannot invoke Lambda AWS on java locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, log4j2, aws-java-sdk

I run the following commands:

```
1) sls create --template aws-java-maven
2) mvn clean install
3) sls invoke local -f hello
```

I got this error:

```
Serverless: In order to get human-readable output, please implement "toString()" method of your "ApiGatewayResponse" object.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.invoke(InvokeBridge.java:95)
    at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.<init>(InvokeBridge.java:39)
    at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.main(InvokeBridge.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger.log([B)V
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2.LambdaAppender.append(LambdaAppender.java:74)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)

    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)

    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2091)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2005)

    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1876)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1421)
    at com.serverless.Handler.handleRequest(Handler.java:18)

    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding both log4j and log4j2 with version 1.0.0 (decreased from 1.1.0) helped ...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why not to accept the answer from @JunedAhsan instead of copy pasting his answer?

Comment: @nickolay.laptev that answer didn't help, it doesn't work with version 1.1.0, only with 1.0.0 for log4j and log4j2

Comment: this didn't fix the issue for me, i'm still getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some runtime logger dependencies. Try adding these to your pom file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, you need to make sure that you are using the compatible version of Java AWS SDK, which is generally the same version number.Something like this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have this in pom.xml

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: @WillGraham what is the java aws sdk verions are you using?

Comment: I use the latest one

Comment: see the answer, it's really strange

Answer (score 0):

This also work for me....

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

In java file add below lines.

```
LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

logger.log("received: " +input.toString());
```